# Shortcut to `cd` into the 2nd folder in a directory

Tags: cd-command

## How to `cd` into the 2nd folder in a directory?

> #### CONTEXT

I am in a directory with 3 folders.
After executing `ls -1` they are ordered like so.

```
folder1
folder2
folder3
```

I want to quickly `cd` into `folder2`.

I was able to write a function to quickly `cd` into `folder1`

this is my function.

```
f1 () {
       cd $(ls -d */|head -n 1)
}
```

> #### QUESTION

I need a function called `f2`. That when executed, `cd`'s into `folder2`.

(the folders are sorted by `ls -1`. I am using `zsh`)

Comment: Crossposted (with a `zsh` tag) here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/499908/shortcut-to-cd-into-the-2nd-folder-in-a-directory

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
cd $(ls -d */| sed -n 2p)
```

`-n` tells `sed` to not print anything by default, and `2p` tells it to print line #2.

Answer (score 2):

simplest way to get second row is

```
ls -d */|head -2|tail -1
```

first get two upper rows, then last of them

the problem is, if you only have one folder, you will get it,  not absent second

Answer (score 1):

Something that doesn't require extra processes:

```
dirs=( */ )
cd "${dirs[3]}"  # 0-based
```